# How to capture subprocess o/p to another fd using python subprocess

Tags: python

I have a shell commandline that **outputs data to a file descriptor** which is different from `stdout` or `stderr`.

When I tried:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen("some cmdline", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
a,b = p1.communicate()
```

I found that both a and b were empty and there was some o/p (logs, which I was trying to catch) send to the console while running the two python commands above.

I understand I might have to redirect the o/p from shell cmdline to stdout or stderr but looks like the fd to which logs are sent by shell cmdline changes every time.

My question is how do I capture the o/p from the shell commandline above into a and / or b?

Comment: It works as expected for me. What OS are you using ? On unix, you can try adding the redirect in the shell command: " 2>&1 " . You might also try some variations and see if it works differently. What happens with stderr=subprocess.PIPE or with shell=False [ You may have to break the command line up into a list of args for that one.]

Comment: @StevenD.Majewski I added some emphasis in my question text. Please take a look. The fd, data is being sent to by shell commandline is not 1 or 2 it is something else and it changes with each invocation.

Comment: Try with 'close_fds=True'  and see if that changes the different fd each invocation issue. ( Maybe it's the parent fds that makes the difference. ). Try adding: " 3>&1 4>&1 5>&1 " and see what happens. ( Maybe more are needed, but maybe not if close_fds=True changes behavior. )

Comment: If you can afford, use a higher level wrapper like the `sh` module.